# add .blur() method to SVG elements in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, svg

Microsoft IE/Edge don't seem to add a .blur() function to SVG elements as most other browsers do. Indeed, most other elements in IE/Edge have a blur funciton.

This is causing me a problem because I'm using a 3rd party library which is trying to call the blur function of event.target when I click on certain elements and I want to use an svg icon on one of those elements.

This is causing the following error in IE

**TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'blur'**

I can't edit the 3rd party library but I was wondering if I could use the element's prototype to add a "fake" blur function to SVGs which does nothing but gets rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seemed to do the trick

```
if (typeof SVGElement.prototype.blur == 'undefined') {
    SVGElement.prototype.blur = function(){};
}
```